# ddrmenu razor doesn't show anything in dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

For our website we want to use a megamenu that is created with razor.

In the Gravity skin folder of DNN, we have created a folder called MegaMenuNav and we have added our MegaMenu.cshtml and menudef.xml into it.

We have downloaded the ddrmenu example and used it like this:

```
<dnn:MENU ID="MENU" MenuStyle="MegaMenuNav" runat="server" NodeSelector="*"></dnn:MENU>
```

we get no error, but nothing is shown as well.

All of the example menus that use token or xslt, such as Dropdown and Mega2DNN are shown, but when we use Razor menus, nothing is shown.

For testing, we added a simple text inside our MegaMenu.cshtml, but again we got no result

Is there anything to do with dotnetnuke?

BTW, we are using .Net 4.5 and Dnn 8.0.2

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the simple megamenu.cshtml template?  Also, is anything being logged in /Portals/_default/Logs?